# Global Xcode run scripts

Tags: xcode, git, build-process, versioning, run-script

In order to automatically update build dates and build numbers, I set up a run script for the build phase in my scheme:

```
# Auto Increment Version Script
buildPlist=${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}
CFBuildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBuildNumber" $buildPlist)
CFBuildNumber=$(($CFBuildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBuildNumber $CFBuildNumber" $buildPlist
# "Mon" is a hack, but day is needed, and in English
CFBuildDate=$(date "+Mon %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBuildDate $CFBuildDate" $buildPlist
```

While this works, the downside is that the schemes are bound to the user-specific settings, i.e. they are are excluded from version control and may easily get lost.

What's the proper way to tackle this problem and make those scripts available to all developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "Shared" checkbox in the scheme settings.  By checking it, your schemes will be saved in the project global settings and not in your user specific settings folder.  This also makes it so that the scheme will be included in an git commit, etc (assuming that the project settings folders arent ignore in gitignore).  You can keep ".xcuserdata" in .gitignore, and the scheme will still be included in your repo.
  screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm I always "edit"ed the existing schemes but never opened the manager to find that checkbox. :)

Comment: Yea, I found it by accident the first time p.

Answer (score 0):

Tick the Shared box in the scheme settings (to save it into the project global settings).